# ASP.NET MVC Returning file from byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to download file, that was earlier but into database as byte[] (varbinary(max) in sql), but when I try to call DownloadCv method I get exception:
"Input Data is not valid base-64 string."

Could You help me find my mistake or show another way to download file please?
Cheers.

Here is what I currently have:

```
public class ApplyForm
{
    /*Some other properties
        ...
    */
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

//Apply View

```
@model SourceTreeITMatchmaking.Core.Model.ApplyForm

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Apply";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <div>
        <!-- Some properties to bind to ApplyForm are not shown here to avoid misunderstandings-->
        <input class="form-control col-md-2" type="file" name="file" />
        <input class="form-control col-md-2" type="submit" value="Upload" />
        <input type="hidden" name="jobOfferId" value="@Model.TargetOfferId" />
    </div>
```

//Apply action after posting form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(HttpPostedFileBase file, ApplyForm applyForm, int jobOfferId)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        applyForm.FileName = file.FileName;
        applyForm.FileSize = file.ContentLength;
        applyForm.FileData = GetFileBytes(file);
        applyForm.ContentType = file.ContentType;

        dbConnection.ApplyForms.Add(applyForm);
        dbConnection.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("JobList", "JobOffer");
    }
}
```

//Method to get byte[] from HttpPostedFileBase

```
private static byte[] GetFileBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var streamLength = file.InputStream.Length;
    var imageBytes = new byte[streamLength];

    file.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    return imageBytes;
}
```

//MyOffersController

```
public ActionResult JobOfferReplies(int jobOfferId)
{
    List<ApplyForm> allReplies = dbConnection.ApplyForms.Where(x => x.TargetOfferId == jobOfferId).ToList();

    return View(allReplies);
}
```

//JobOfferReplies View

```
@model List<SourceTreeITMatchmaking.Core.Model.ApplyForm>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "JobOfferReplies";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Download CV", "DownloadCv", "MyOffers", new {file = applyForm.FileData, contentType = applyForm.ContentType }, new { @class = "btn btn-default pull-left" })
<div>
```

//MyOffersController

```
public FileContentResult DownloadCv(byte[] file, string contentType)
{
    return new FileContentResult(file, contentType);
}
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: Full error message: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters

Comment: Stack trace:
   System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength) +11961555
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +130
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.ByteArrayModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +98
   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IModelBinder_BindModel.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +118
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +80

Comment: Seems like there is some problem when I want transfer applyForm.FileData from View to Controller in this line:

     @Html.ActionLink("Download CV", "DownloadCv", "MyOffers", new {file = applyForm.FileData, contentType = applyForm.ContentType }, new { @class = "btn btn-default pull-left" })

Because in DownloadCV method I get null for file byte[] but contentType is ok.

Comment: Why does your `DownloadCv()` action method have a byte array parameter?

Comment: I wanted to pass FileData which is my file in byte[] to that method and download a file. Something might be a bit odd with my thinking tho :)

I have changed FileData to string, converting byte[] to String64 and passing it from view to controller but i have "
HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long."

Comment: Okay, nevermind I solved it :) Im now passing only Id, not whole byte[] :)

And then in controller I just search database for specified ID.

Sorry for bothering You :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our code we do it as follows:

```
entityItem= new byte[file.ContentLength];
file.InputStream.Read(entityItem, 0, file.ContentLength);
file.InputStream.Close();
```

And to return

```
return File(entityItem, "application/octet-stream");
```